# Jupyter/Python/Docker. Need to get an output csv

Tags: python, docker

have the following:

**Hello.ipynb**

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Max', 'Oleg', 'John'],
                      'results' : [100, 2, 3]})
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Scripts\df.csv', index = False)
```

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:latest
    RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
    COPY . /usr/src/app/
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
    
    RUN pip3 install jupyter
    RUN pip3 install pandas
    RUN jupyter nbconvert --to python Hello.ipynb
    
    CMD ["python", "Hello.py"]
```

```
> docker run -v /Scripts:/usr/src/app app
python: can't open file 'Hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: You might find it substantially easier to run this in a virtual environment, which will be able to both directly access the script file and the data files without special setup.

Comment: please check that if your Hello.py exists or not and if yes then in which directory

Comment: Mates, the goal here is using Docker. Concerning Hello.py it's being produced in container as I understand and I can not reach it? It's a image layer...

Comment: Is `df.to_csv(r'C:\Scripts\df.csv', index = False)` READING FROM or WRITING TO that file?

Answer (score 0):

You are OVERWRITING the directory.

You have first said "Copy the application and source code to `/usr/src/app`. Then said, "ignore that, overwrite the entire `/usr/src/app` directory with `/Scripts` by using `-v /Scripts:/usr/src/app`.

---

To fix.

1. Send the volume to a DIFFERENT directory.  `/mnt` is perfect for that.
2. Your docker container only knows about the files IN the container.  Since you are sending the volume to `/mnt`, you must change your `C:\Scripts\` to `/mnt`.

Comment: I've changed in command line to docker run -v /mnt:/usr/src/app app and added this folder to File sharing directory in settings of Docker. As a result I have an empty mnt folder and the same warning about Hello.py. Maybe Dockerfile is someway wrong?

Comment: sorry maybe I missed something in your answer?

Comment: "maybe I missed something", yes, you did.  Give a read to https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ pay close attention to "source" and "target".